# Developing iPhone software for bluetooth or WiFi device (guidelines)

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth, wifi

I have for example 5 lights and 2 speakers which I want to connect to my iPhone via Bluetooth or WiFi. I want to play music and turn lights on and off via iPhone costume made software.

So where I should start? 
What should I read (webpages, forums)? 
What kind of hardware do I need?
Any good examples?

Any guidelines or tips are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CoreBluetooth

The CoreBluetooth framework provides access to Bluetooth 4.0 low energy devices.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CoreBluetooth_Framework/_index.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TemperatureSensor/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40012194